# UIView.animateWithDuration doesn't animate on separate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Setting animation to fade in and out repeatedly.
'viewSmall' and 'viewBig' are UIImageViews.

[view storyboard shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aCu3.png)

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewBig: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewSmall: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        animate()
    }

    func animate() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                                   delay: 0,
                                   options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse],
                                   animations: {
                                    self.viewSmall.alpha = 0
            },
                                   completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                                   delay: 0,
                                   options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse],
                                   animations: {
                                    self.viewBig.alpha = 0
            },
                                   completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This code doesn't animate on a only few view controllers, and the view controllers seem independent, no segue to other view controllers, on my guess. Because this code works perfectly on view controllers connected to navigation view controller.

How can I make it on independent view controller?
Please help.

Comment: "Because his code works perfectly " who's code ? Please pose complete code and describe in detail what do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. it means 'because this code...'

Comment: I still does not get your problem. Animation is not working ? or it is not working on some specific viewController ? if so then show that viewController's code and your storyboard as well

Comment: Added screen shot and full code. thanks.

Comment: Your code works on my viewController without Navigation Controller as you describe on your question, so i can't reproduce what is wrong

Comment: Oh, then my guess was wrong. What's the reason.... :(

Comment: @ReinierMelian Would you please let me know how did you open the ViewController? In my case, used self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Was my first ViewController, maybe that is why this works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a brilliant solution.
Used dispatch_after to catch duration and delay.

```
func animate(){
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        // Animate the transition
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                               delay: 0,
                               options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse],
                               animations: {
                                self.viewSmall.alpha = 0
        },
                               completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
                               delay: 0,
                               options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse],
                               animations: {
                                self.viewBig.alpha = 0
        },
                               completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Source from:
[Swift UIView animateWithDuration completion closure called immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626515/swift-uiview-animatewithduration-completion-closure-called-immediately)